# Access job filename parameter in SkipPolicy of Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

I have a job with Spring Batch which I read some files with BeanIO, and I would handle invalid files, so I created a SkipPolicy class.

```
public class FileVerificationSkipper implements SkipPolicy {

    private static final FluentLogger LOGGER = LoggerService.init(FileVerificationSkipper.class);

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkip(Throwable exception, int skipCount) throws SkipLimitExceededException {
        if (exception instanceof FileNotFoundException) {
            return false;
        }

        if (exception instanceof BeanReaderException && skipCount <= 10) {
            LOGGER.all().logKey("Error on read file: ").value(exception).asError();
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

On my reader step I access the name like this: `@Value("#{jobParameters['input.file.name']}") String inputFile`

I would like to log the filename, how could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging how Spring Batch inject the parameters I found the solution.

I just need to add `@StepScope` in the class and create the variable where I want to inject the parameter:

```
@Component
@StepScope
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FileVerificationSkipper implements SkipPolicy {

    @Value("#{jobParameters['input.file.name']}")
    private String inputFile;

    ...

}
```